# creating dynamic element in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, element

Am creating elements dynamically using

```
var eType = "div";
document.createElement(eType);
```

is there anyway to validate the provided string is an equivalent html tag.

if i provide something like `var eType = "idv";` it has to send an error.

Any workarounds to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isValid(input) {
   return document.createElement(input).toString() != "[object HTMLUnknownElement]";
}

alert(isValid("div"));
```

Not enough rep to flag, but duplication source: [Verify whether a string is a valid HTML tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286663/verify-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-html-tag-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
var validTags = ['div'];
function is_tag(tag) {
    return validTags.indexOf(tag.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Check there if it's an html tag: 

if (eType == "div"){

document.createElement(eType);

}
```

Comment: This is good but however you'll need || for every tag. In my answer it's just adding a new value to the array. Not saying your way is wrong, it can be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to have included all valid tagNames and then see if `[object HTMLUnknownElement]`

```
function isValidHTMLTag(tagName, allowObsolete) {   //  use `-1` as second parameter to completely bypass allowObsolete check
    var obsolete = ['acronym', 'applet', 'basefont', 'bgsound', 'big', 'blink', 'center', 'dir', 'font', 'frame', 'frameset', 'hgroup', 'isindex', 'listing', 'marquee', 'multicol', 'nextid', 'nobr', 'noembed', 'noframes', 'plaintext', 'spacer', 'strike', 'tt', 'xmp'];
    return tagName.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) ? !1 : -1 !== allowObsolete && -1 !== obsolete.indexOf(tagName) ? allowObsolete || !1 : "[object HTMLUnknownElement]" !== Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement(tagName));
}
```