# How to perform case insensitive lookup in javascript set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

How to perform case-insensitve lookup in javascript's `set`?

I have a situation where I have a set of allowed strings which doesn't ensure what case they would be in. I need to validate a user input against that set. How can I achieve this?

```
const countries = new Set();
countries.add("USA");
countries.add("japan");

// returns false, but is there any way I could get 
//`my set to ignore case and return true?`
console.log(countries.has("usa")); 

console.log(countries.has("USA"));
```

Comment: A way to achieve this is put all what you need in your set is upperCase then .has("string".toUpperCase())

Comment: you can rewrite the .has method to ignore case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just always call `.toLowerCase` on the string before you add it or before performing a `.has` check. For sure you can also abstract that into a class (if thats really necessary):

```
 class CaseInsensitiveSet extends Set {
   constructor(values) {
     super(Array.from(values, it => it.toLowerCase()));
   }

   add(str) {
     return super.add(str.toLowerCase());
   }

   has(str) {
     return super.has(str.toLowerCase());
   }

   delete(str) {
     return super.delete(str.toLowerCase());
   }
}

const countries = new CaseInsensitiveSet([
  "Usa",
]);

console.log(countries.has("usa")); // true
```

Comment: May also add 'trim' as well as a part of transformation, i.e. str.trim().toLowerCase()

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no". [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) uses SameValueZero algorithm to seek for a value's existence. See the comparison table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value-zero_equality).

If performance is not a concern, you can try two searches, one with uppercased value, and one with lowercased value, and decide whether the value actually exists.

And the better approach would be to always insert the values by converting them to uppercase/lowercase and match accordingly for existence.

Comment: Thank-you, but I may have the entries in the set in mixed case as well. I will take approach of adding to set after uppercasing the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Sets check the exact data you have provided. The simplest solution is to save the data in lowercase or UPPERCASE and then search over the set using the `.toLoserCase()` `String` method.

Example:

```
// Save data in lowecase
const set1 = new Set(['test', 'other']);

console.log(set1.has('Test'));
// expected output: false

console.log(set1.has('Other'.toLowerCase()));
// expected output: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `hasIgnoreCase()` prototype on `Set`.

```js
Set.prototype.hasIgnoreCase = function(str) {
  return this.has(str) || this.has(str.toUpperCase());
}

const countries = new Set();
countries.add("USA");
countries.add("japan");



// returns false, but is there any way I could get 
//`my set to ignore case and return true?`
console.log(countries.hasIgnoreCase("usa"));

console.log(countries.hasIgnoreCase("USA"));
```

Comment: Thank-you but will this work if the items in the set is in mixed case? the set I receive doesn't guarantee the case, so it may be mixed case as well.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler if that's the case then the solution wont work, you will have to go with the accepted answer only.