# Is there any way to find the unknown html tag from string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce

I want to find the unknown html tag from the string.

Eg: '<span>hello</span><p>address</p><span><Enter Your Name></span>'

Here I want extract the unknownhtmltag from a string. Above string is just for  example data inside string will be dynamic.

Comment: If your name is a variable in angular component.ts you have to call in your component.html with string interpolation {{yourNameVariable}}

Comment: Actully I'm using the tinyMce and My task is to uplaod the doc file and show the text in the tinymce editor but some  users are using angle brackets t in the string and tinymce consider angle brackets as an html tags.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the [`DomParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) parse the HTML.
- Get all the tags in the document using `getElementsByTagName("*")`
- Call the`toString` method on each element and see which of them are invalid ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287085))

Here's a snippet:

```js
const htmlString = "<span>hello</span><p>address</p><span><Enter Your Name></span>",
      
      parsedDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html"),
      
      allElements = Array.from( parsedDoc.getElementsByTagName("*") ),
      
      isInvalid = e => e.toString() == "[object HTMLUnknownElement]",
      
      invalidElements = allElements.filter(isInvalid)

console.log(invalidElements)
```

Comment: This one is only returning the half tag name for example: <enter your name> is the tag name it just returning the enter.

Comment: @Mandeep yeah. That is how html is parsed. `<enter>` will be the tag and the other 2 are treated as attributes. Space is not allowed in tag names

Comment: Is there any way to get those attribute with tag it will be great help to me.